# Getting error from class while selecting dataset in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
With Chat_Kernel as(

SELECT conferenceId, chat_creation_date_Asia_Kolkata, chat_start_date_Asia_Kolkata, chat_start_url, referrer, chat_duration_in_seconds, queue_duration_in_seconds, visitor_livechat_id, visitor_nick, visitor_ip, visitor_email, last_operator_id, `group`, group_name, rate, last_rate_comment, goal_action_name

FROM `bigquery-405008.Kernel_GA4.Kernel_chat` 
GROUP BY conferenceId, chat_creation_date_Asia_Kolkata, chat_start_date_Asia_Kolkata, chat_start_url, referrer, chat_duration_in_seconds, queue_duration_in_seconds, visitor_livechat_id, visitor_nick, visitor_ip, visitor_email, last_operator_id, `group`, group_name, rate, last_rate_comment, goal_action_name
--ORDER BY COUNT(chat_start_url)
LIMIT 1000
),
NewQ1 as(
SELECT 
Chat_Kernel.referrer
ORDER BY COUNT(chat_start_url)
FROM Chat_Kernel
--GROUP BY conferenceId, chat_creation_date_Asia_Kolkata, chat_start_date_Asia_Kolkata, chat_start_url, referrer, chat_duration_in_seconds, queue_duration_in_seconds, visitor_livechat_id, visitor_nick, visitor_ip, visitor_email, last_operator_id, `group`, group_name, rate, last_rate_comment, goal_action_name

)

SELECT NewQ1.*,
from NewQ1
```

Getting error from class while selecting dataset in bigquery and how to sort from column name referrer

[To know more click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1P4b.png)

Comment: So, what error are you getting? Also, all questions need to be self-contained so please don’t include links to other sites. Please update your question with any relevant information that your link contains

Comment: FROM Chat_Kernel is not working

Comment: That doesn’t really help. What is the full/complete error message you get when you run this query? Also, why are you using a GROUP BY when you aren’t aggregating anything?

Comment: The Error is 

Syntax error: Expected ")" but got keyword FROM at [14:1]

Answer (score -1):

ORDER BY goes after the FROM not before it.

Also, having an ORDER BY in a CTE is pointless as it doesn’t do anything

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you can you please provide code so that I can easily understand

Comment: I edited the code and it worked as per your suggestion but have one more issue. I have the code.

I want to to sort multiple same duplicate hyperlink from referrer cloumn which contains same like 'google', 'direct' etc. and after sorting the result should come with all similar hyperlink in sequence from  referrer cloumn. Sorry for my bad English try to understand what am I looking for

Comment: As that is a new question I suggest you raise a new question on this forum. Make sure you include  1) the currently working SQL you've written 2) Enough sample data for your source table to illustrate all possible use cases 3) the result you want to achieve based on the source data. Please make sure this is all as editable text in your question and doesn't link to external sites - unless you want to create a dbfiddle (to complement the information in your question not as a substitute for writing a self-contained question)